# Using a using block but still ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, stream

I want to add multiple streams into my `MultiformDataContent` and I'm doing it like this:

```cs
 MultipartFormDataContent formdata = new MultipartFormDataContent();
 foreach (var item in files)
 {
     using (FileStream fs = File.Open(item, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
         HttpContent content = new StreamContent(fs);
         formdata.Add(content, "files", item.Split(charSeparators)[2]);
     }
}
// send the content to the backend, parse results
var result = client.PostAsync(url, formdata).Result; // ObjectDisposedException
```

but when I check my content length, it's `null` and the `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line simply wraps `fs` in a `StreamContent` object.

```
HttpContent content = new StreamContent(fs);
```

The stream isn't read until you call `PostAsync`:

```
client.PostAsync(url, formdata)
```

At which point you have already closed the stream. You should dispose of the stream after you have posted it. `MultipartFormDataContent` will dispose of any content objects it contains, and that will in term dispose of the stream, so you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
using(MultipartFormDataContent formdata = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        FileStream fs = File.Open(item, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        HttpContent content = new StreamContent(fs);
        formdata.Add(content, "files", item.Split(charSeparators)[2]);
    }
    // send the content to the backend, parse results
    var result = client.PostAsync(url, formdata).Result;
}
```

[Proof that it disposes correctly](https://rextester.com/AWBZ97820).

Comment: I've done that but now it throws an exception on the fact that I'm trying to use the same file for multiple processes (I'm using mock files)

Comment: @Mout I suspect you'll need to pass a 4th parameter to `File.Open`: `FileShare.Read` to allow you to open multiple read streams to the same file.